# Problem with last update hyperref

Tags: hyperref

Since this morning (and maybe the update 7.0.b of hyperref) my docs can't be compiled... I tried with APMEP's files and same problem... If I uncheck hyperref & hypersetup lines, it's ok...

In the hyperref's website, I saw taht the current version was 7.0.c but even if I install it manually, I've got problem with my personal class...

Btw, with my personal class, I've lot of packages, which are currently loading hyperref package... so I'm in trouble for my personal docs...

```
Undefined control sequence. \hypersetup.
Missing number, treated as zero. \hypersetup
```

Comment: Tomorrow it should be ok again, the fix is already on ctan. Add for now `\chardef\OpMode=20` before loading hyperref. If this doesn't help (and if you really already use version 7.00c) you will have to make a complete example and show it along with the log.

Comment: `Undefined control sequence. \hypersetup.` is not the format of a tex error message, perhaps just a summary from some editor? please show a full small test document and a full log file.

Comment: Tks for answers, I've tried some stuff and it seems that a filename with space characters generate problem... I tried with the fix (chardef ) but the problem is not present when I remove space in filename... weird because before no problem with spaces in filename.

Comment: It is not weird at all it is a known issue in hyperref 7.00b and its fixed in 7.00c but we only know that as we knew it before, you haven't provided enough information to see what versions you have or what errors you are getting.

Comment: I'm using last update in CTAN, the 7.0.b version of hyperref, if my filename doesn't contains space its ok, if it contains space :
`! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.`

Comment: yes, there are currently two (unrelated) bugs, one in hyperref (affecting compilation with latex), and one affecting files with spaces. Both should be resolved tomorrow. I guessed that you are speaking of the first, but as your error message was truncated it was only a guess.

Comment: Tks, okay for the resolving tomorrow, for now I've just remove spaces in my filenames and add \chardef within my class ;-)